# How to establish trailing return type of lambda function that use template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, trailing-return-type

How can I make trailing return type deduction in the following code snippet that uses a template function?
Code works well as it is now, but I need to know if I can also add trailing return for the lambda function..

```
template<class T>
T print(T a){
    cout << a;
    return a;
};

int main()
{
    auto print_int = [](int a)/*->How?*/{
        return print<int>(a);
    };
    print_int(4);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```cpp
auto print_int = [](int a) -> decltype(print<int>(a)) {
    return print<int>(a);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
auto print_int = [](int a) -> auto {
    return print<int>(a);
};
```

or

```
auto print_int = [](int a) -> decltype(auto) {
    return print<int>(a);
};
```